# Is there an easy way to get the size of a specific network folder?

Tags: http

This URL: http://sun3d.cs.princeton.edu/data/ has a list of folders that I want to download but I'm not sure what the total size would be before I download them all.

Is there an easy way to figure this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The total of all files is 9.7GB If you look just below Parent Directory you'll see SUNRGBD.zip and adjacent to that is Last Modified then Size. All the subsequent files are just the contents within the zipped folder. So if you download the zipped folder you will get all the files.